# Is it possible to boot an existing windows installation from hard disk with VirtualBox in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have a dual boot system windows 7 and Linux Ubuntu 10.4, I want to clarify if it is possible to load the windows installation through Linux VirtualBox from the existing installation at hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it actually is, and the procedure was quite straightforward, the most recent version of VirtualBox supports loading a native installation in the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will see the hardware as having changed. At best, it will complain loudly. Most likely, however, is that it won't work.

Comment: I manage to open my image successfully from my ubuntu with virtualbox there was an issue with a specific version of the kernel. Windows didn't complain at all.